# Should I removeBehavior a UIPushBehavior -- I am adding many pushes

Tags: ios, uikit-dynamics, uidynamicbehavior

I have a small UIView that bounces in a box. I am adding an **Instantaneous** mode. push. In fact I am adding very many pushes -- 5 or more Hz.

Mystery:

(1) Do I have to **removeBehavior????**  if so .. **when**?!?  "after" an "instant" ?

(2) Is it that UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous is a special case, and you do not have to (or cannot) remove those??

(3) When you addBehavior: does that .. retain?! the UIPushBehavior?  Or??  WTF?!

(4) I couldn't seem to find these aspects documented anywhere!

```
-(void)pushMeRight:(CGFloat)mag
    {
    if ( self.bounceAnimator == nil ) return;
    NSLog(@"...........push me right %.2f", mag);

    UIPushBehavior *pushRight = [[UIPushBehavior alloc]
            initWithItems:@[self]
            mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];

    pushRight.magnitude = mag;
    pushRight.angle = radians(0);   // (NB, 0 is right, 90 is down)
    [self.bounceAnimator addBehavior:pushRight];
    }
```

{Note: I simply alloc the UIPushBehavior **each time** I need one. Note that if you try to use "just one" as a property, it **does not work**. In fact, Rob explains why below.}

---

**Solution**

After extremely extensive testing, we found that Rob's "second" solution, using the .action, is essentially perfect.

Again after vast testing, we would very strongly recommend that the following code, is, really, **"the solution"**, the only way to code repetitive pushes..  Thank goodness for Rob  :/

```
-(void)pushAllUp:(CGFloat)mag
    {
    if ( self.bounceAnimator == nil ) return;
    for ( UIView *pushme in self.subviews )
        {
        UIPushBehavior *pp =
        [[UIPushBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[ pushme ]
             mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];

        pp.magnitude = mag;
        pp.angle = radians(270); // (NB, 0 is right, 90 is down)

        UIPushBehavior __weak *weakPP = pp;
        pp.action = ^{ if (!weakPP.active)
             [self.bounceAnimator removeBehavior:weakPP];};

        [self.bounceAnimator addBehavior:pp];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. Yes, you are adding that `UIPushBehavior` correctly.
2. You technically don't have to call `removeBehavior` for an instantaneous push because the behavior will have its `active` status turned off as soon as the instantaneous push takes place.

   Having said that, I'd be inclined to remove the behavior because you're otherwise taking up memory, with the animator maintaining a strong reference to these non-`active` instantaneous push behaviors. (This is easily verified by logging the animator's `behaviors` property, which is an array of all of the behaviors it is keeping track of.) There might eventually be a performance related issue for it to iterate through all of these non-`active` behaviors, too, though I suspect the memory concerns are probably of more significant interest.

   But unlike other behaviors (e.g. `UISnapBehavior`) which stay `active`, you don't have to worry about lingering instantaneous push behaviors continuing to affect the items to which it was added.
3. They don't "expire", *per se*, but, yes, they quickly go to an `active` state of `NO`.
4. Yes, when you add a behavior to the animator, the animator will maintain a strong reference to it until you remove the behavior.

Personally, I'd be inclined to remove the behavior after adding it. Because it's instantaneous, the timing of its removal isn't terribly critical, and you could do something as simple as:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.animator removeBehavior:push];
});
```

Or, you could set up an `action` that removed it for you.

```
UIPushBehavior *push = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:self.items mode:UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous];
push.pushDirection = ...

UIPushBehavior __weak *weakPush = push;  // avoid strong reference cycle
push.action = ^{
    if (!weakPush.active) {
        [self.animator removeBehavior:weakPush];
    }
};

[self.animator addBehavior:push];
```

Comment: thanks for this!  I must do some tests to see when you can remove the behaviour: does the behaviour happen "then" at that line of code; or, only at the end of the routine (or more like a frame-driven game engine).  I'll find out...

Comment: The animator does not perform the behaviors until you yield the main thread back to the run loop (i.e. your routine exits). So, make sure you never block the main thread. (This is a general rule, so make sure you avoid blocking the main thread at any point, or else you'll adversely affect the animator's ability to perform the animations.) But the fact that you have to wait for the animator to pick up the behavior is why you don't just remove the behavior immediately, but rather remove it asynchronously (i.e. after some delay, or better, when the `action` block is called).

Comment: Ah OK, well you've answered that question - awesome!

Comment: PS the .action idea .. is incredible.

Comment: I'm traveling this weekend, so I'm not sure if I'll have a chance to look at it before I get back next week, but I'll try to carve out a few min...

Comment: thanks @rob we tested massively and indeed your .action solution is flawless.  we did have some problems trying, as a curiosity, just "a short delay and the releasing".  **Footnote** you may have noticed this yourself already .. we found on most devices, iOS **really hates it** if you for some reason just move offscreen, a view which is being sent pushes. It doesn't work, you have to be careful to turn of gyros or accel. on and off if you have a view going in and out (or another one coming in). Hope it helps some future reader